# Count multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have a flat file in Excel, it has more than 200k of rows, and I need to have multiple criteria.

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

for example, I need to count how many meet the condition

```
CodiAdmi = 106

DesCont = EV MEDICAL SERVICES 2019

DCodiServ = to a list of codes ..
```

Using filters can be done, but the codes of DCodiServ are many and it takes me too long to select them.

You can guide me by creating some macro or formula.
thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question. We cannot guide you from scratch, we can only assist you to fix issues in the code you have written or if you get stuck during coding (if you show us your code).

Comment: You don't need code to do this.  You could do this with a pivot table.  Filter on the first two values then show the count for the remaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using sum over countifs would give you what you are looking for. Like for example, assuming you have 200 rows, you may use:

```
=sum(countifs("A1:A200",106, "B1:B200","EV MEDICAL SERVICES 2019", "C1:C200",{"890701","890602O"}))
```

Notice the use of curly braces to add a list of comma separated criteria for filtering the last column.

Comment: Thank you very much, can you select the criteria of a range of cells?